# Get just the integer value of the image width from SIPS, without "pixelWidth: ..."

Tags: bash, sips

When getting an image's pixelWidth using SIPS it outputs with a heading. e.g.

```
sips -g pixelWidth $images
```

returns

```
"  pixelWidth: 1920"
```

I'm trying to get the integer part only, with no luck:

```
sips -g pixelWidth $images | grep \d+$
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use grep's -E (regex) and -o (capture matches) flags, this works for me:

```
sips -g pixelWidth menu_icon.png | grep -Eo "\d+"
```

**Note** if you have any numbers in your file path to the image(s), they will show up (since sips prints the file path too), so you might want to add grep `pixelWidth` before you grep out the number, like this:

```
sips -g pixelWidth menu_icon.png | grep pixelWidth | grep -Eo "\d+"
```

Comment: I don't think GNU grep with ERE supports `\d` - mine doesn't. It requires `-P` to match a digit with `\d`. For BRE and ERE, there is always `[[:digit:]]`, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just an easy-to-read, robust alternative as you already have a working answer, you could use `awk` like this:

```
sips -g pixelWidth image.png | awk '/pixelWidth:/{print $2}'
```

That says... *"on lines that contain the word 'pixelWidth:', please print the second field."*